# jQuery emulate Click at Intervals

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-click-event

Is it possible to emulate a Click on a Link or any Tag at a set Interval ?

Reason: I have a plugin that doesnt have auto Rotate Feature but works only on click of the Next and Prev Link. So i am trying to write a function that does the clicking automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to repeatedly call a function and fire click event within that function using [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or directly call click().

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#ElementId').trigger('click');
 // $('#ElementId').click();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var checkForConfirmation = function(){
      $("#anchorLink").trigger('click');
}
var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){checkForConfirmation()}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#ElementId').click();
}, 5000);
```